# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, ajax, database, oracle

Hi I have an error that says "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes)".

Basically, in the php file I extract the information that the user chooses to do a search with the function I created in a package in an ORACLE data base. In php I call the function, pass in the parameters and display all the results.

```
<?php  
$db_connection = oci_connect('DBadmin', 'dbadmin', 'PETLOVERSDB');
if (!$db_connection) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}   

$type =  $_GET['type'];  
echo $type;

$result;
$resultArray;
$finalResult = ' ';

$sqlVariableFindMyPets = 'BEGIN :pet_variable := pet_search_package.pet_search_type(:p_type_data);END;';   
$result = oci_new_cursor($db_connection);     

$dataToReceive = oci_parse($db_connection, $sqlVariableFindMyPets);      

oci_bind_by_name($dataToReceive, ':pet_variable', $result, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);  
oci_bind_by_name($dataToReceive, ':p_type_data', $type); 
oci_execute($dataToReceive); 
oci_execute($result, OCI_DEFAULT); 
oci_fetch_all($result, $resultArray, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);


oci_close($db_connection);  

if($resultArray == null){
    echo "<h2>No results found<h2>";
} else { 
    foreach($resultArray as $iterator){
        $finalResult = $finalResult.'<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"> 
                                        <div class="properties">
                                            <form action="pet-detail.php" method="POST">
                                                <h4>'.$iterator['PET_TYPE_NAME'].' </h4>
                                                <div class="image-holder"><img src="images/logo2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="properties"/></div>
                                                <h5>'.$iterator['PET_RACE_NAME'].' </h5> 
                                                <h5>'.$iterator['PET_COLOR'].' </h5>  
                                                <h5>'.$iterator['PET_ENERGY_LEVEL'].'</h5>
                                                <h5>'.$iterator['PET_COND_NAME'].'</h5> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_code" value="'.$iterator['PET_CODE'].'"/>  
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_name" value="'.$iterator['PET_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_type" value="'.$iterator['PET_TYPE_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_race" value="'.$iterator['PET_RACE_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_cond" value="'.$iterator['PET_COND_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_energy" value="'.$iterator['PET_ENERGY_LEVEL'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_learn" value="'.$iterator['PET_LEARN_SKILL'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_vet" value="'.$iterator['VET_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_p_name" value="'.$iterator['PERSON_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_location" value="'.$iterator['PETLOCATION'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_notes" value="'.$iterator['PETNOTES'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_space" value="'.$iterator['PET_SPACE'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_treatment" value="'.$iterator['PET_TREATMENT'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_color" value="'.$iterator['PET_COLOR'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_sickness" value="'.$iterator['PET_SICKNESS_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_med" value="'.$iterator['PET_MED_NAME'].'"/>   
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="View Details" />
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                       </div>'; 
    }
    echo $finalResult;
}

?>
```

And the function in ORACLE is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pet_search_package AS
       FUNCTION pet_search_type(TYPEPET in VARCHAR2)
       RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
       IS 
          pet_search_result SYS_REFCURSOR; 
          type_id NUMBER;

       BEGIN  

       select TP.pet_type_code into type_id
       from dbadmin.petType TP
       where TP.pet_type_name = TYPEPET;

    OPEN pet_search_result FOR select pet_type_name, pet_race_name, pet_cond_name, pet_energy_level, pet_learn_skill, vet_name, person_name, petlocation, petnotes, petabandondescription, pet_space, pet_treatment, pet_color, pet_sickness_name, pet_med_name
    from pet, pettype, petrace, petCondition, petSize,petEnergy, petlearningskill, veterinary, person, petSpace, pettreatments, petcolor, petsickness, petmedicine
    WHERE pettype.pet_type_code = type_id;
        RETURN pet_search_result; 

      EXCEPTION 
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
          RETURN null;
      END; 

END pet_search_package;
```

I have tried putting `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` on the php file but it doesn't seem to work. I also read that I have to increase variables ? which variables and where ? What can I do to solve this problem? Im not sure what is going on. Please, any suggestions would be appreciated !

PS. I tried the function on the database and works just fine

Comment: After you update the php.ini file, you'll need to restart your web server for it to take effect.  I'm not sure about Windows/Mac but on Linux, you'll have two php.ini files, one for the cli and one for your web server.

Comment: @Chad: 128 MB memory is more than enough. the algorithm should be improved. guess what happens if that script is ever run by 100 users simultanuously? wanna buy a mainframe? the main problem is that the script uses too much memory because it reads everything in at once instead of processing each bit at a time. see the answer below, and my comment below...

Comment: @Michael Of course.  But I wasn't providing an answer, only a comment.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a large table and your program fails while preparing the output.

instead of doing :

```
        foreach($resultArray as $iterator){
            $finalResult = $finalResult.'<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"> 
                                            <div class="properties">
                                                <form action="pet-detail.php" method="POST">
                                                    <h4>'.$iterator['PET_TYPE_NAME'].' </h4>
                                                    <div class="image-holder"><img src="images/logo2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="properties"/></div>
                                                    <h5>'.$iterator['PET_RACE_NAME'].' </h5> 
                                                    <h5>'.$iterator['PET_COLOR'].' </h5>  
                                                    <h5>'.$iterator['PET_ENERGY_LEVEL'].'</h5>
                                                    <h5>'.$iterator['PET_COND_NAME'].'</h5> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_code" value="'.$iterator['PET_CODE'].'"/>  
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_name" value="'.$iterator['PET_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_type" value="'.$iterator['PET_TYPE_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_race" value="'.$iterator['PET_RACE_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_cond" value="'.$iterator['PET_COND_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_energy" value="'.$iterator['PET_ENERGY_LEVEL'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_learn" value="'.$iterator['PET_LEARN_SKILL'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_vet" value="'.$iterator['VET_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_p_name" value="'.$iterator['PERSON_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_location" value="'.$iterator['PETLOCATION'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_notes" value="'.$iterator['PETNOTES'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_space" value="'.$iterator['PET_SPACE'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_treatment" value="'.$iterator['PET_TREATMENT'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_color" value="'.$iterator['PET_COLOR'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_sickness" value="'.$iterator['PET_SICKNESS_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_med" value="'.$iterator['PET_MED_NAME'].'"/>   
                                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="View Details" />
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                           </div>'; 
        }
        echo $finalResult;
```

try this foreach loop:

```
        foreach($resultArray as $iterator){
            echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"> 
                                            <div class="properties">
                                                <form action="pet-detail.php" method="POST">
                                                    <h4>'.$iterator['PET_TYPE_NAME'].' </h4>
                                                    <div class="image-holder"><img src="images/logo2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="properties"/></div>
                                                    <h5>'.$iterator['PET_RACE_NAME'].' </h5> 
                                                    <h5>'.$iterator['PET_COLOR'].' </h5>  
                                                    <h5>'.$iterator['PET_ENERGY_LEVEL'].'</h5>
                                                    <h5>'.$iterator['PET_COND_NAME'].'</h5> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_code" value="'.$iterator['PET_CODE'].'"/>  
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_name" value="'.$iterator['PET_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_type" value="'.$iterator['PET_TYPE_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_race" value="'.$iterator['PET_RACE_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_cond" value="'.$iterator['PET_COND_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_energy" value="'.$iterator['PET_ENERGY_LEVEL'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_learn" value="'.$iterator['PET_LEARN_SKILL'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_vet" value="'.$iterator['VET_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_p_name" value="'.$iterator['PERSON_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_location" value="'.$iterator['PETLOCATION'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_notes" value="'.$iterator['PETNOTES'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_space" value="'.$iterator['PET_SPACE'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_treatment" value="'.$iterator['PET_TREATMENT'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_color" value="'.$iterator['PET_COLOR'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_sickness" value="'.$iterator['PET_SICKNESS_NAME'].'"/> 
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" readonly name="pet_med" value="'.$iterator['PET_MED_NAME'].'"/>   
                                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="View Details" />
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                           </div>'; 
        }
```

So just display the results as you iterate through them. Your code will have a more efficient use of memory.

Comment: don't forget this line from the original post: `oci_fetch_all($result, $resultArray, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);` that problem is just as big..

Comment: What exactly should I do with oci_fetch_all($result, $resultArray, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW); ?

Comment: @Michael so, you think the problem isn't the memory but the implementation?

Comment: @MMYW: maybe there is a function like oci_fetch_row... or something like that? so that you can read each row at a time and print it. in pseudocode: `while($row = oci_fetch_row(...)) { print_row($row); }` one more thing.. you need to disable output buffering, because otherwise it will still grow very big. anyhow.. how big is the resultset? is it 10000 rows or more? I'm just asking because I want to understand why the script wants to consume >128MB RAM..

Comment: @MMYW: don't worry about the output buffering.. i'm not 100% sure about that. i think if you don't call ob_start() yourself, it will print as soon as 4KB are in the buffer (or even earlier maybe)

Comment: I'd say go step by step. To begin, try just improving the way that the output is handled, as I stated, and see how that goes. If the program fails before reaching the foreach($resultArray) loop, then you'll have to find a way to optimize the exchange with the db (oci functions) as suggested Michael. If even that doesn't get you there you'll have to look for other posible problems. I'd say debug one step at a time.

Comment: Also check your apache server log. You'll have your **"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728...."** error there stating what line of code triggered it. This will indicate you how far did you code go before failing.

Comment: @Michael The strange part is that i have another function  FUNCTION find_myPets(user_id person.person_id%type) that takes another type of parameter and the result is normally bigger. Its implemented in the exact same way but i don't get that error message. I don't understand how thats possible